# Localization when using time.Format

Tags: time, localization, go

In the `time` package, when formatting a `time.Time` variable, the output will use the English names for weeks and months as defined in unexported []string slices.

How to localize the string, using a different language (hopefully still using `Format()`)?

**Example:**

```
fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("Mon 2 January 2006"))
```

**Output:**

> Tue 28 January 2014

**Desired output:**

> Tis 28 Januari 2014

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/7CrE9G02s0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see in time package [sourcecode](http://golang.org/src/pkg/time/format.go#L249) that values are hardcoded in source. So, basically, Go doesn't support i18n right now. i18n is on Go roadmap, its even mentioned in the [faq](http://golang.org/doc/faq#What_is_the_status_of_the_project), but there were no comments on that topic recently.

Meanwhile, you could try to use [Monday](https://github.com/goodsign/monday/) package:

```
  // Change LocaleEnUS to the locale you want to use for translation
  monday.Format(time.Now(), "Mon 2 January 2006", monday.LocaleEnUS)
```

Comment: I was afraid that was the case. Thanks for pointing out a workaround package. Saves me time!

Comment: is this still the case in 2022? Is Monday still the recommended way, or has this made it in to the standard library?